# visualforce:Toggle checkbox not functioning well

Tags: visualforce

can anyone help me with my code my toggle checkbox won't work in visualforce page here my code.

```
<div class="slds-box slds-box_small">
                        <div class="slds-form-element">
                            <b>sample toggle</b>
                            <label class="slds-checkbox_toggle slds-grid">
                                    <input id="toggle1" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" aria-describedby="toggle-desc" />       
                                <span id="toggle-desc" class="slds-checkbox--faux_container" aria-live="assertive">
                                  <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
                                  <span class="slds-checkbox--on">Enabled</span>
                                  <span class="slds-checkbox--off">Disabled</span>
                                </span>
                            </label>
                       </div>
                    </div>
```

and here's my js code:

```
<script>

    j$('#toggle1').on('change',function() {
    //The syntax inside the if statement below returns true for toggle checked and false for toggle unchecked
           if(j$(this).prop('checked')){
               j$('#toggle1').text('On');
           }else{
               j$('#toggleValue1').text('Off');
           }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by not functioning well? It would be better if you explain what exactly is not working well. However, if you mean the text below the toggle, then you dont really need JS for that. Try below:

```
<apex:slds />
<div class="slds-box slds-box_small">
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <b>sample toggle</b>
        <label class="slds-checkbox_toggle slds-grid">
            <input id="toggle1" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" aria-describedby="toggle-desc" />       
            <span id="toggle-desc" class="slds-checkbox_faux_container" aria-live="assertive">
                <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
                <span class="slds-checkbox_on">On</span>
                <span class="slds-checkbox_off">Off</span>
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```